# C# - how to remove ctrl M characters when transferring files from windows to unix using Tectia?

Tags: c#, windows, unix, newline

In a C# module, I want to transfer files from Windows to Unix using Tectia. But the problem is when these files are transferred(Ascii or Binary mode both) and opened using VI editor we get ^M characters.
I searched about this but the solutions are to remove these ^M characters after the files are transferred using utilites. Is there any way that these ^M characters do not appear in the first place.
Is there any option to have a workaround in code before sending these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everyone. I solved this problem using a workaround. 
Windows uses CR+LF (\r\n) as end-of-line & Unix uses LF (\n) as end-of-line.I took the Windows file and replaced the occurrence of CR+LF(\r\n) with LF(\n) in code itself without any utility.This made the file compatible for Unix systems and then I transferred the file using SFTP and it worked on Unix without ^M characters.

Answer (score 26):

How I was able to remove it in vi editor:

- After `:%s/` then press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. This will give you `^M`
- Then `//g`   (will look like: `:%s/^M` ) press <kbd>Enter</kbd> should get all removed.

Good luck!

Comment: this key-by-key input is absolutely necessary as copy and paste won't do the trick.

Comment: This just doesn't work if you're using vi from a terminal in windows because the control characters don't work the same way. The dos2unix solution is simplest if you have the ability to install it (I added it to my docker dev environment)

Answer (score 19):

If you just need to remove the `^M` characters (not replace them with `\n`):

```
sed -i -e 's/\r//g' yourfile.txt
```

If you want to replace them with `\n`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r/\n/g' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

You can install and use [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix). After Installation just run:

```
>dos2unix yourfile.txt
```

Comment: hi...I know about dos2unix utility but Is there any way that these ctrl M characters do not appear only?

Comment: Unix uses a single Line Feed (LF) character as line break. Windows/DOS uses 2 characters: Carriage Return/Line Feed (CR/LF). So the answer is no, you cannot eliminate the CR\LF (unless you write all your text in one line).

Comment: @RaviGoklani I'm not aware of a windows tool that does such conversions, but since you use `vim` [*this article*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) might interest you.

Comment: this worked for me without the `>`, only; i.e. `dos2unix yourfile.txt`

Comment: The `>` is just the prompt sign ;)

Answer (score 5):

One more trick to remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in vi editor:

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

For more trick to [remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> characters](http://spytm.com/find-remove-controlm-characters-unix/)

Answer (score 3):

Try executing the following in your terminal (may need to install it first):

```
fromdos <your-file>
```

Comment: actually I dont want to run anything on UNIX after transfer is done..no command,no utility etc....just my file should be transferred from Windows to Unix without those ^M characters

Comment: Then you need to make sure you set the file to UNIX file format before sending your file over. I believe it's the EOL (line endings) that are causing it, any decent text editor will allow you to change the line ending type.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/^V^M//
```

1. `g` not needed at all.
2. `%s` - find and replace text that u want to replace
3. `^V^M` to be replaced with "should be after double slash" keep it empty if you want to replace with nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tr -d '\015' <INPUT_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE
```

Comment: tr -d '\015' <INPUT_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE

Answer (score 0):

`tr '\015' '\n' < /tmp/file-with-ctrlm.txt > /tmp/no-ctrlm.txt`

- This command uses ASCII code of CtrlM and replaces all CtrlM with newline characters.
- It avoids Ctrl-V, Ctrl-M, and works on Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is the only thing that would work .. not unix2dos or anything ...

sed -e 's/\x0D//g'

reference:

The hexadecimal 0a, a control character as opposed to a printing character, is called a line feed.

The hexadecimal 0d is called a carriage return.